# overwrite existing files from codepipeline deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy some new code using aws codepipeline. The first time it works no problem, the second time the deployment fails because of existing files. How can I instruct my flow to overwrite existing files?

Error Message:
The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location:

Comment: Can you specify what type of deployment you are doing? Maybe share a bit of the code, or an example bit of code, that represents the step in the pipeline that isn't working as you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to deploy is **to delete the project directory and kill the process before deploying**. This let the state of the project directory keep pure and in sync with the original repository.

As you can see from this link([appspec.yml hooks for deploying to EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server)), CodeDeploy download artifacts on `Install` phase and we cannot access to that step. `Install` phase comes after `BeforeInstall` hook.

So you should delete the directory and kill the processes **before 
`Install` phase to be executed.**

```
hooks:
   BeforeInstall:
     - location: codedeploy-scripts/deleteAndKill.sh
   #   runas: root # this might be needed depending on your setting.
```

Define `codedeploy-scripts/deleteAndKill.sh` properly and try running `CodePipeline` and `CodeDeploy` again.

P.S. Deleting the project directory and killing the processes are somewhat bothering. so once you use `docker`, what you have to do is only `docker stop {container name}` and `docker run {image name}`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using VSTS AWS codedeploy connector, using that I was able to overwrite existing files.